# Concat two columns with leading zeroes in the second column value, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to concat values from two columns with a specific format for the second column value. The second column value should be in "0000" format.
I have my current query like this

```
SELECT 
     ISNULL(BatchID,'')+ISNULL(UID,'') as BatchIDUID 
FROM 
     myTable 
WHERE 
     id=249
```

which gives me output

```
1509161               //BatchID = 150961 and UID = 1
```

it should be in the format

```
1509160001            //BatchID = 150961 and UID = 1
1509160022            //BatchID = 150961 and UID = 22
1509160333            //BatchID = 150961 and UID = 333
1509164444            //BatchID = 150961 and UID = 4444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a note, you can do this using arithmetic and not converting the values to strings:

```
select COALESCE(BatchId, 0) * 10000 + COALESCE(UId, 0)
```

You can then cast this as a string:

```
select CAST(COALESCE(BatchId, 0) * 10000 + COALESCE(UId, 0) as VARCHAR(10))
```

This happens to work for your values, which fit in an integer.  However, you can support longer values by using decimals:

```
select COALESCE(CAST(BatchId as DECIMAL(20, 0)), 0) * 10000 + COALESCE(UId, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `RIGHT`

```
SELECT 
     ISNULL(BatchID,'')+ISNULL(RIGHT('0000' + UID, 4),'') as BatchIDUID 
FROM myTable 
WHERE  id=249;
```

General approach:

```
DECLARE @pad INT = 4;
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @pad) + /* column/variable */, @pad);
```